# Attempting at centering UILabel in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I'm attempting at centering a UILabel, but it doesn't seem to be responding. This is my intuitive code, though I'm certain it's far from the best way to do this..

```
    let sanskritLabel  = UILabel(frame: CGRectZero)
        sanskritLabel.text = page!.sanskrit!
        sanskritLabel.frame.size.width  = self.view.frame.size.width
        sanskritLabel.textAlignment     = .Center
        sanskritLabel.numberOfLines     = 0
        sanskritLabel.layer.borderColor       = UIColor.cyanColor().CGColor
        sanskritLabel.layer.borderWidth       = 3.0;
        sanskritLabel.center            = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.width/2, verse.frame.origin.y + chapterStringSize.height + 20)
        sanskritLabel.sizeToFit()
```

I used this on other UILabels below this one, and they seem to center just fine. In this case, this UILabel `sanskritLabel` , appears floated to the left :

[image]

Which is strange because I'm explicitly saying that the **width** should be `self.view.frame.size.width` , but it seems to be either ignoring that.

I imagine that if the width was set to be exactly as I'm declaring it ( 375 ), then the text would be centered fine because of the `.textAlignment` attribute.

Any idea why this isn't working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Jonah said, you're resizing the view with `sizeToFit`, after setting the `frame` with `center`. so when the view is resized, it changes the `size` but keeps the same `origin`.  To fix the problem call `sizeToFit` before you set the `center`:

```
sanskritLabel.sizeToFit()
sanskritLabel.center = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.width/2, verse.frame.origin.y + chapterStringSize.height + 20)
```

Comment: Ah ok, fascinating. I'm assuming this seems like a practical way to accomplish this as well? SizeToFit just specifies the width so I guess I can remove the width call.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling [sizeToFit](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/sizeToFit) which updates the label's frame:

```
- sizeToFit
Resizes and moves the receiver view so it just encloses its subviews.
```